# git update-index --assume-unchanged - get list of "unchanged" files

Tags: git

So I run:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <FILE>
```

command couple of times for some files. Now, how do I get the list of all temporary ignored files?

Comment: [`git ls-files -v`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)

Comment: @David Did we answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git ls-files -v | grep --perl-regexp '^[a-z]\s' | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=2-
```

...lists all files with the "assume unchanged" flag set.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page of `git update-index`:

> To see which files have the "assume unchanged" bit set, use git
>   ls-files -v (see git-ls-files(1)).